# Bet with NBA players

Tags: probability

> Giannis of Milwaukee Bucks and  Kyle Lowry of Toronto Raptors are having lunch together at a restaurant. Giannis claims that if their teams play against each other, Raptors will lose with probability 3 out of 5, while Kyle claims that Raptors will win with probability 4 out of 7. 
>   The waiter, who overhears the conversation, decides to make some money himself, by challenging one of the two, or even both, to go on a bet with him. He wants to make some money regardless of the outcome of the game. He is thinking of suggesting to Giannis of Kyle (or both) that, if his team wins, the waiter will have to pay him A dollars, while if his team loses, he (or they – if they bet together) will have to pay him B dollars. Obviously the bet must be favorable for Giannis or / and Kyle, in order for them to accept it and, if the waiter proposes a bet to both, it must be with the same amount for each of them.
>
> What will be the amounts A and B?

I wish I could show you some work but I haven't been able to do anything! I even gave it to two friends of mine, who are mathematicians and they haven't come back with any solution yet!

I assume we must compare the two probabilities for Raptors to win (one says 2 of 5 and the other 4 of 7). But I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Do people upvote this for the mention of NBA? 22 views, 11 upvotes, hard to believe...

Comment: Do we know anything about the true probabilities that either team wins? And can we decide if we want to propose a bet to both of them or to just one person? And do we want to maximize our expected money gain?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch:  the point is that you have a sure thing because of the odds offered.  The chance that each team wins does not matter.

Comment: @RossMillikan I see, that clears it up

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $G$ and $L$ are willing to trade on their exact probabilities (this is unrealistic, since both should demand a positive expectation bet).

Then you can place a $\$100$ bet with $G$ on the Bucks using $G's$ odds (of course you bet that the Bucks lose, $G$ bets that they win).  Since $G$ sees a $\frac 35$ chance of winning, $G$ sees that as worth $\frac 35\times 100=60$.  Since $G$ sees a $\frac 25$ chance of losing, he must offer $X$ such that $\frac 25\times X = 60$ so he offers you $\$150$ should you win.

You also place a $\$100$ bet with $L$ on the Raptors using $L's$ odds (of course you bet that the Raptors lose, $L$ bets that they win).  Since $L$ sees a $\frac 47$ chance of winning he sees that $100$ as worth $\frac 47\times 100$.  To be fair, he then must offer to pay out $\frac 73\times \frac 47\times 100 =\frac 43\times 100=133.\overline 3$.

Payouts:  If the Bucks win, you receive $133.\overline 3$ from $L$ and hand $100$ to $G$, giving you a profit of $33.\overline 3$.

If the Raptors win you receive a payout of $150$ from $G$ and you hand $100$ to $L$, giving you a profit of $50$.

Either way you win (and you can afford to sweeten the odds a bit to induce the players to bet with you).

Note: nothing above made any reference to the "true" probability for the winner in the game.  The only way that matters is if you want to compute the value of this double bet to you.  As it stands all we know is that this position is worth somehwere betweeen $33.\overline 3 $ and $50$.

Comment: If you want, you can adjust the size of the bets so you win the same amount no matter who wins.  That is what the bookies try to do.

Comment: Dear lulu, thank you for your reply; I just noticed that I hadn't interpreted the puzzle correctly, so I had to make an edit: "He wants to make some money regardless of the outcome of the game". The bet (with only one or both of the players) must be such, that the waiter will win anyway!

Comment: In my version the waiter wins no matter what, as I point out in my post.  He either wins $33.\overline 3$ or he wins $50$.  As @RossMillikan points out, it's an easy matter to scale the bets to level that out, if that matters to you.  That is you can guarantee winning a fixed dollar amount by betting less on one side.  I'll leave that (simple) calculation to you.

Comment: Hmmm I can accept 133 instead of 150 from Giannis if I win, and exactly the same to Kyle. This means, if the Bucks win (in which case, Raptors lose), I pay Giannis 100 but Raptors pay me 133 so I win 33. Same also if Raptors win, I pay them 100 and I win 133 from Bucks so again I win 33. Is this what you mean? Because the bet must be exactly the same (same amounts) for both.

Comment: I don't understand.  In my system I bet $\$100$ with each, I thought that was what you required.  That  leads to unequal winnings depending on the outcome, but so what?

Comment: To clarify:  in order to level the payouts, you need to have different bets with each.  I thought you wanted the same bets (i.e. same dollar amount on your side)  so I wrote it up that way.  At this point, though, I am not sure what it is you want.

Comment: The bet has two parameters: I give you A amount if I lose and you give me B amount if I win. If I bet with both Giannis and Kyle, A and B must be the same for both. Otherwise, I must bet ONLY with one of the two guys (but the bet must be such, that I must win regardless of the outcome of the game).

Comment: Those are strange rules.  Since those rules disregard the odds each of the two players set, I'm not sure what the point would be.  But if you want to, then just tell G that he can pay you $133.\overline 3$ should Toronto win.  He should jump at this bet, since (using his odds) he'd be willing to pay you considerably more.